# Selecting max confidence category using pandas and numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataset

I am stuck in caluculating the highest of the 3 columns and respctive category as per the dataset:

<[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iG3U.jpg)>

I want to calculate the max confidence category with confidence level and create a dataset with 4 columns like:
TC_Name   Failure   MaxErrCategory   MaxConfidence

I have tried capturing the max confidence level for each row but unable to figure out the category:

```
max_conf=data.max(axis=1)
```

Kindly help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idxmax method of the dataframe will give you, for each row, the name of the column where the first occurrence of the maximum has been found.

```
data.idxmax(axis=1)
```

As you have strings in some of your columns, you should first select the columns on which you want to compute the max:

```
data[ ["confidence1", "confidence2", "confidence3"] ].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: But i have strings also in rows, it's throwing me error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Script'.

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account your remark.